# Multiplying any number with null should return null instead of 0 in typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, null

I have a scenario where in C#,

```
decimal? x; // number
decimal? y; // null
c=x*y //c returns null
```

where in typescript

```
let x:number=null;
let y:number=12;
c=x*y //c returns 0
```

**How to get null instead of 0 in typescript ?

I need to set generic way instead of using ternary operator and checking both properties null and returning null.

Is there any compiler options I need to set in tsconfig.json ?**

Comment: well, Typescript follows javascript / Ecmascript conventions. when doing math operations, some implicit conversions are done, and in particular null can be coerced to the number 0.

Comment: is there any way to return null, because I need to save zero as zero and null as null in SQL

Comment: `null * number` should be `NaN`, not `null`..?

Comment: Um, if you declare a C# variable as `int y`, its value isn't ever going to be `null`.

Comment: @Teemu : `undefined` * number is NaN in JS / TS. But null gets converted to zero.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQBSNLIDQPKY  
@Teemu

Comment: @gary Yep, but I said "_it should be `NaN`_." Accoding to any logic, `null * number` is not a number, neither it is `null` ..? That code snippet is a typical victim of the automatic type coercion JS does.

Comment: @gary never use w3schools.com. it is not a remotely credible reference. For your own sake you need to find something better

Answer (score 7):

**Why the result is zero in your case**

Because in TypeScript/JS/ES, an arithmetic operation involving a number and `null` will cause `null` to be implicit converted to a number. And null gets converted to 0.

If you want the "C# null-swallowing" behavior, you indeed need to specify it explicitly :

```js
let c = x === null || y === null ? null : x * y;
```

The 'natural' behavior in Typescript is the same as JavaScript / EcmaScript : if you have an operation with a number and null, null will be coerced to the number 0.

> Is there any compiler options I need to set in tsconfig.json ?**

To my knowledge, there isn't, and there shouldn't be, because that's how arithmetic operations work in ES / JS, and TS has no reason to try changing the arithmetic rules of ES towards the one used by C#.

---

> I need to set generic way instead of using ternary operator and checking both p> properties null and returning null.

**Another solution with NaN / undefined**

To avoid this code cluttering and have a similar "some special values swallows every operation" like `null` in C#, you could maybe use `NaN` (Not a  Number) instead of nulls.

This

1. would be easy to just transform every null into NaN.
2. any operation like x * y will give NaN if any operand is NaN, without any change to the code that performs computations.
3. If you really need nulls at the end then you can convert back NaNs to null. (be careful, to test for a number to be NaN, use `Math.IsNan()`, never try to compare with `=== NaN` as this will always give false, even `NaN === NaN`)
4. As a last but not least remark, if one of the operand is `undefined`, the result of an operation will *also* be `NaN`. So actually, you could as well turn your nulls to undefined instead of NaNs, the conversion from C# `null` to JS/TS `undefined` might be more natural. Might be easier on the serialization side as well (hint : `Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore`)

It is not sure this can be adapted to your situation, but it's worth checking if you want to avoid cluttering your code with conditionals like I wrote above.

Comment: How can `int x` be null ?

Comment: I am already doing this but I want to handle it in a generic way because I am having around 2000 lines of calculations code.

Comment: That is for example to demonstrate the scenario  @Eser

Comment: @Eser I was assuming there is was a typo and OP was talking about `int?`. Anyway, his question was more about 'how to get null in Typescript operation if one of the operand is null`, I focused on answering this part.

Comment: Thanks..!, That was my question exactly @Pac0

Comment: @gary : a *maybe better way* to use automatic "swallowing" of any 'null's would be to turn `null` into `NaN`. Then, **any operation involving a `NaN` will return a `NaN`. This seems like the behavior you want, and this allows you to keep all your operations without any conditional check before.

Comment: This is very good and definitely a sound approach. You've explained it clearly but you'd do well to add that C#'s `null`, in nonarithmetic contexts, maps to JavaScript's `undefined`. Actually, as I suspect the issue relates to serialization boundaries, it's a shame that JSON doesn't allow `NaN`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad well, effectively realized that while writing my 4th point, but didn't know how to formulate that nicely. I tried to elaborate a bit more in my last edit, but by all means, feel free to edit my answer yourself if you want.

Comment: @Pac0 great! I think I'll leave it as it is I think you touched on it well. Quite right about serialization ease since we can use `Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore` and actually get symmetry.

Comment: @Pac0 If we go through the approach NaN/Undefined then we can handle multiplication but if it is sum it is returning NaN instead of Zero.

`let x=null;
let y=20; 
x+y = 20`
the same scenario after changing null to NaN or Undefined
`x+y =NaN`

Comment: @gary sure... but wasn't that exactly the point ? That *any* operation involving NaN/undefined will return NaN, as in C# any operation involving null would return null ?

Comment: If you do not want a global solution, if you want 'nulls' to still be handled as `0` for addition, then I don't see any solution that to to specifically use conditionals before the only operations where you want a null result.